# Textbox not setting the value as null when the user cleans the text field in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have the next textbox:

```
<TextBox FontSize="10">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="EstatusAdministrativo" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <validations:IsRequiredValidationRule />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

This textbox is binded to a variable in the ViewModel that looks like this:

```
private string _EstatusAdministrativo;
public string EstatusAdministrativo {
 get {
  return _EstatusAdministrativo;
 }
 set {
  _EstatusAdministrativo = value;
  OnPropertyChanged();
 }
}
```

The validation inside of the textbox looks like this:

```
public class IsRequiredValidationRule: ValidationRule {
 public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo) {
  string strValue = Convert.ToString(value);
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strValue))
   return new ValidationResult(false, $ "Por favor llenar este campo.");
  return new ValidationResult(true, null);
 }
}
```

When I delete all the characters in the textbox, the value of EstatusAdministrativos is not setting as null. It doesn't trigger the set method when I clean the textbox. Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Comment: did you try with IsNullOrEmpty instead of IsNullOrWhiteSpace?

Comment: I had a similar problem with a TextBox binding to a null int property. The empty text box never set a null value via the binding, e.g. when the text was deleted. It worked when I added 
         TargetNullValue=''
to the Xaml binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source property isn't set when the validation rules fails unless you set the `ValidationStep` property to `UpdatedValue`:

```
<validations:IsRequiredValidationRule ValidationStep="UpdatedValue" />
```

This will cause the validation rule to run *after* the source property has been set. You can read more about this in [this](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/08/26/data-validation-in-wpf/) blog post.

If you need more control, you should get rid of the validation rule and implement the [INotifyDataErrorInfo](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19490.wpf-4-5-validating-data-in-using-the-inotifydataerrorinfo-interface.aspx) interface in your view model class.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to set `ValidatesOnDataErrors = false`. This could be preventing the textbox from updating the property value if the entered value does not validate.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.validatesondataerrors?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I had setted it to false, but doesn't work. I have removed the validtaion rule from Binding.ValidationRules and is setting the variable as "" but I need to keep the validation. Is there a say to do it?

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
return new ValidationResult(true, null);
```

you should call

```
return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
```

Comment: btw i prefer IDataErrorInfo in my Viewmodels